# Using Unity ExternalTexture on Android

Tags: javascript, c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use external texture when bringing  PNG files from Android Smartphone with Unity3D and JavaScript.

SetupExternalTexture is same as below, I got nativeTextureID

```
nativeTextureID = _activity.Call<System.Int32>("SetupExternalTexture");

public int SetupExternalTexture() {
  int textureid[] = new int[1];
  GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureid, 0);
  UnityTextureNativeID = textureid[0];
  //String pictureDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download/sa.jpg";
  String pictureDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Pictures/untitled.png";
  //Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/untitled.png");
  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pictureDirectory);
  ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bitmap.getByteCount());
  bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(byteBuffer);
  prevWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
  prevHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
  GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
  GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, UnityTextureNativeID);
  GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, 0, bitmap, 0);
  //GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, prevWidth, prevHeight, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, byteBuffer);
  GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
  GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
  GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

  return UnityTextureNativeID;
}
```

and I use Texture2D.CreateExternalTexture in Unity

```
Unity  texture = Texture2D.CreateExternalTexture(texWidth, texHeight, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false, false, new System.IntPtr(nativeTextureID));
```

but, I got strange this Image... Help me Anybody

//strange image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SH1hy.jpg)

//want image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gbLZ.png)

Comment: Can't you also add what you are expecting to see?

Comment: normal picture (.png file)

Comment: Yes, but what does that png file look like? It might be helpful to understand whether colors bytes are shifting etc.

Comment: I edit ! upload I want picture